# GetOwnedGames from SteamAPI Not Working?

Tags: json, steam-web-api

I'm trying to get the hours of TF2 played from Steam profiles for an application I'm developing. I'm not very experienced at manipulating JSON, so I'm not sure if the API is bad or if I'm bad.

According to this: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetOwnedGames_.28v0001.29 I can call include_played_free_games to show TF2. However when I make a web request using this: `http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v1/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&include_played_free_games=true&format=json&steamid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

The request is valid, however TF2, appid 440, doesn't show up. So am I going crazy, or should this be working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user has to have played the game at some point for it to be returned when specifying 'include_played_free_games'.

From the [API Documentation](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetOwnedGames_.28v0001.29):

> include_played_free_games: By default, free games like Team Fortress 2
>   are excluded (as technically everyone owns them). If
>   include_played_free_games is set, they will be returned **if the player
>   has played them at some point**. This is the same behavior as the games
>   list on the Steam Community.

The url requires a numeric value '1' for the parameters and will not work if you use 'true'. The following url worked for me when using my own steam id and web key:

http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&**include_played_free_games=1**&**include_appinfo=1**&format=json&steamid=XXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: I tried it on an account that has played it and it still did not show up.

Comment: try adding include_appinfo=true so that you get the game names, what exactly is being returned could you post the json? are you getting any games back?

Comment: With this request: http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v1/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&include_played_free_games=true&include_appinfo=true&format=json&steamid=76561198044976145 I get this: http://pastebin.com/qDZhfepG

Comment: You have include_appinfo=true but that is not returned in the json,  are you using a browser, could the browser be caching this?

Comment: I tried in multiple browsers that I had never used before, with the same result.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I didn't even think of that.

Comment: `The url requires a numeric value '1' for the parameters and will not work if you use 'true'.` You, sir, are a lifesaver.